# How to create Mapping of a connected list

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have a list of, or we can say a chain of, items in a database table, which are connected with each other like:

```
 item_id   connected_item  item_cost  item_type
 100       200              12        anything
 200       300              11        anything
 300       400              14        anything
 400       500              19        anything
 ..........
```

How can I know that if I input 200 it will give me both connections to it, which are 100 and 300. And also, the list of connected items between two items e.g. if first `item=100`, last `item=300` then all items are `100,200,300`. And the approach should also work bottom to top e.g. if first `item=300`, last `item=100` then all items are `300,200,100` including cost and type.

Comment: You should include more details, i.e. your data structure. As it stands, it's impossible to answer. Also, you should mention what you've tried so far. I see no relevance to any of the given tags either.

Comment: If you're developing for iOS... is this an SQLite database, perhaps? Or some other format?

Comment: Yes its SQLite database, there is no problem in loading data I loaded the given data in a class name 'Items' with properties having above column names. Now the only logic is to get connections of station as i stated above.